# How detect the mouse back and forward buttons in a Delphi FMX Windows form?

Tags: windows, delphi, mouseevent, firemonkey

Has anyone found a way to detect the mouse back and forward buttons in a Delphi FMX form in Windows (and only Windows)?

I understand this works fine in a VCL application, using

```
procedure WMAppCommand(var Msg: Winapi.Messages.TMessage); message WM_APPCOMMAND;
```

but this has no effect in an FMX application.

If anyone already has worked out a solution to this, would very much appreciate a hint (or the code they used, of course).

Comment: Are you sure your mouse is generating WM_AppComand's and not simply simulating Keyboard commands like `VK_BROWSER_BACK` and `VK_BROWSER_FORWARD`?  If it is simulating key commands then all you need to do is use `OnKeyDown` or `OnKeyUp` events respectively.  You would be surprised of how often these additional buttons on mice simply send specific keyboard commands to the computer.

Comment: @SilverWarior Yes, I am. The OnKeyDown and OnKeyUp events were among the first things I checked. They are not triggered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FMX heavily filters window messages, only dispatching the few messages it actually uses for itself. `WM_APPCOMMAND` is not one of them, which is why a simple `message` handler does not work in FMX, like it does in VCL.

So, you are going to have to manually subclass the `TForm`'s Win32 `HWND` directly, via [`SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) or [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass), in order to intercept window messages before FMX sees them.  See [Subclassing controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview).

An ideal place to do that subclassing is to override the [`TForm.CreateHandle()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCustomForm.CreateHandle) method.  You can use FMX's [`FormToHWND()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) function to get the `TForm`'s `HWND` after it has been created.

```pascal
protected
  procedure CreateHandle; override;

...

uses
  FMX.Platform.Win, Winapi.Windows, Winapi.CommCtrl;

function MySubclassProc(hWnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM;
  uIdSubclass: UINT_PTR; dwRefData: DWORD_PTR): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  case uMsg of
    WM_APPCOMMAND: begin
     // use TMyForm(dwRefData) as needed...
    end;
    WM_NCDESTROY:
      RemoveWindowSubclass(hWnd, @MySubclassProc, uIdSubclass);
  end;
  Result := DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure TMyForm.CreateHandle;
begin
  inherited;
  SetWindowSubclass(FormToHWND(Self), @MySubclassProc, 1, DWORD_PTR(Self));
end;

procedure InitStandardClasses;
var 
  ICC: TInitCommonControlsEx;
begin
  ICC.dwSize := SizeOf(TInitCommonControlsEx);
  ICC.dwICC := ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;
  InitCommonControlsEx(ICC);
end;

initialization
  InitStandardClasses;
```

Comment: Edited some of your answer. Hope you don't mind. With those changes, it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @Domus care to share what you changed?

Comment: It says it needs to be approved by a trusted community member. Surely, that must be you? I changed the "procedure" into "function", Added "Result := DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam)" at the end of the function, and added "var
  ICC: TInitCommonControlsEx;

initialization

  ICC.dwSize := SizeOf(TInitCommonControlsEx);
  ICC.dwICC := ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES;
  InitCommonControlsEx(ICC);" at the end.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add it also needs Winapi.CommCtrl in the uses clause. Odd, I had added all that in the edit.