# Intercepting Window status, position etc. in Firemonkey

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, firemonkey, windows-messages

I have user-friendliness in mind, so I'd like to intercept the position of each form I'm opening, to store and retrieve each time the same form is opened again.

Because I plan to port this for MAC, I decided to use FireMonkey.

Unfortunately, there is no event which is fired when a form is moved on the screen. I tried to intercept the message which should be fired when moving, but because nothing is happening, I think that Firemonkey forms do not work as VCL forms.

I'm using this declaration:

```
protected
  procedure WndMethod(var Msg: TMessage); virtual;
```

and this method implementation

```
procedure TMYForm.WndMethod(var Msg : TMessage);
var
  Handled: Boolean;
begin
  // Assume we handle message
  Handled := True;
  case Msg.Msg of
    WM_MOVE : begin
                Edit_X.Text :='x - ' + MYForm.Left.ToString;
                Edit_Y.Text :='y - ' + MYForm.Top.ToString;
              end;
    else
       Handled := False;
  end;
  if Handled then
    // We handled message - record in message result
    Msg.Result := 0
  else
    // We didn't handle message
    // pass to DefWindowProc and record result
    Msg.Result := DefWindowProc(FHWnd, Msg.Msg,
      Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
end;
```

I try to move the form on the screen, but no event is intercepted. I placed a breakpoint in the beginning of the method implementation, but nothing happens until I close the form. In this case, a message is intercepted.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are not overriding any pre-existing virtual method, you are creating your own virtual method that is not hooked up to anything.  That is why it never gets called.

Second, unlike VCL, FireMonkey *does not* dispatch window messages to a virtual `WndProc` method that you can override, or to any `message` handlers that you may define on your form's class.  A handful of select window messages are processed internally only (in a private `WndProc()` function inside the `FMX.Platform.Win` unit), they are not exposed publicly. Any unprocessed messages (including `WM_MOVE`) are discarded.

So, on Windows, the only way to intercept window messages in FireMonkey is to call the Win32 [`SetWindowSubclass()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) or [`SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) API to hook the form's underlying Win32 `HWND` directly (see [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) on MSDN for more details). You can override the form's virtual `CreateHandle()` method to call the API. You can get the `HWND` by calling the RTL's [`Platform.Win.FormToHWND()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND) function.

See [How detect the mouse back and forward buttons in a Delphi FMX Windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143972/) for an example of such subclassing.

Needless to say, using the Win32 API will not port to MacOS, however.  So, you will have to use whatever platform-specific API that MacOS exposes to hook windows.  I don't know what such an API looks like.  And there is no function like `FormToHWND()` in the `FMX.Platform.Mac` unit, but there is a `WindowHandleToPlatform()` function that you can pass the form's `Handle` to. On MacOS, `WindowHandleToPlatform()` returns a `TMacWindowHandle` object containing `Wnd: NSWindow`, `View: NSView`, and `Handle: TOCLocal` properties which you can use with native MacOS APIs.

That being said, there is a better alternative - you do not need to hook the underlying platform window directly at all, you can use [FireMonkey's Save State](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/FireMonkey_Save_State) feature instead.  In the form's `OnSaveState` event, save the form's current `Left`/`Top` values to the form's [`SaveState`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.SaveState) property as needed, and then in the form's `OnCreate` event, you can restore the values from the `SaveState` property, if they were previously saved.